# add additional legend in boxplot abbreviations

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I have a problem with adding legend with explanation of abbreviations. Fo example

```
df <- data.frame(value = c(seq(1,50,1),seq(21,70,1),seq(41,90,1)),
             name = c(rep("A-B",50),rep("B-C",50),rep("A-C",50)))

ggplot(df, aes(name, value))+
geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

I have data.frame with explanation of abbreviations.

```
full_name <- data.frame(abb =c("A","B","C"),fname = c("Ananas","Banana","Cucumber"))
```

I want to add legend with info what each letter means.

Comment: You might want to look up here http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Legends_(ggplot2)/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(df, aes(name, value))+
  geom_boxplot()

library(gridExtra)
grid.arrange(p, tableGrob(full_name, rows = NULL), nrow = 1, widths = c(4, 1))
```

[image: resulting plot]

Answer (score 1):

```
#add fill=name generates legend
ggplot(df, aes(name, value, fill=name)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
#customize legend
scale_fill_discrete(name="Legend\nTitle",
                                breaks=c("A-B", "B-C", "A-C"),
                                labels=c("Ananas-Banana", "Banana-Cucumber", "Ananas-Cucumber"))
```

[image]

Comment: It is a misleading legend.

Comment: Do you know the way to hide little boxplot icons to remain only text legend?

Comment: @NicolaBogucky You can adjust the labels of the legend like you want. The example above should only demonstrate how one can add a legend and customize the labels. I changed the text in my example above.

Comment: [Here](https://cloud.github.com/downloads/hadley/ggplot2/guide-col.pdf) you will find a documentation how to do changes and additions to ggplot2.

Answer (score 1):

The following code makes an additional vector "Legend" and displays it as legend.

```
df <- data.frame(value = c(seq(1,50,1),seq(21,70,1),seq(41,90,1)),
             name = c(rep("A-B",50),rep("B-C",50),rep("A-C",50)))

Legend <- as.character(df$name)
Legend <- replace(Legend, Legend=="A-B", "A-B = Ananas-Banana")
Legend <- replace(Legend, Legend=="A-C", "A-C = Ananas-Cucumber")
Legend <- replace(Legend, Legend=="B-C", "B-C = Banana-Cucumber")

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = name, y = value, colour = Legend))+
geom_boxplot()
```

[image]